# Selenium scraping from repeated hierarchy

Tags: java, selenium, web-scraping

I have a html hierarchy and I want to extract some the information from it. The HTML hierarchy is as follows:

```
<div class="span">
    <div class="da">
        <div class="db">
            <div class="dc">
                <ul class="ua"   id="ua_id"  >
                    <li class="la_id">
                        <div class="de  details">
                            <div class="df">
                                <div class="dg">                                    
                                    <span class="th">
                                        <p class="p4">p: 4</p></span>
                                        <p class="where">Description</p>
                                        <div class='dh'>
                                            <div class='di'>
                                                <div>08 Oct 2016</div>
                                                <div class="dj">loc</div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="la_id">
                        <div class="de  details">
                            <div class="df">
                                <div class="dg">                                    
                                    <span class="th">
                                        <p class="p3 plus">p: 3 plus</p></span>
                                        <p class="where">Description</p>
                                        <div class='dh'>
                                            <div class='di'>
                                                <div>02 Oct 2016</div>
                                                <div class="dj">loc</div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The `<li>` tag gets repeated and I want to extract the details inside

I tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
List<WebElement> details =driver.findElements(By.className("la_id"));
for(WebElement e : details){
System.out.println(e.getAttribute("where"));
}
```

and I can not figure out either how to get the values like in:

```
<div class="dj">loc</div>
```

can someone please give me a hint on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case "where" is not an attribute of the element you found.

If you need to find element with class "`where`" then according to your example you can find it the same way you found another element:

```
List<WebElement> details =driver.findElements(By.className("where"));
   for(WebElement e : details){
   System.out.println(e.getText());
}
```

If you want to locate it using a parent element in your tree you can use something like:

```
List<WebElement> details =driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("li.la_id p.where"));
```

Comment: Thanks Denis, that is fantastic. I love your second suggestion also. But what about a div inside a class like '<div class='di'><div>08 Oct 2016</div></div>'?

Comment: @Selrac then use cssSelector or xPath to locate it. With CssSelector it would be "div.di > div"

Comment: Thanks Denis, you are  a star.